# How to upload pictures using preloadjs?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to upload pictures, but when I go to my page, it displays an error in the browser console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/stuff/170407220921-07-iconic-mountains-pitons-restricted.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ''  is therefore not allowed access.

How to fix it, here is the code?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Preload Images example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/preloadjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var manifest;
var preload;
var progressText = new createjs.Text("", "20px Arial", "#dd4814");
progressText.x = 125 - progressText.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
progressText.y = 20;
stage.addChild(progressText);
stage.update();


function setupManifest() {
    manifest = [ 
    {
        src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/stuff/mountains-clouds.jpg",
        id: "image1"
    }, 
    {
        src:  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/stuff/adventure-alpine-alps-714258.jpg",
        id: "image2"
    },
    {
        src:  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/stuff/170407220921-07-iconic-mountains-pitons-restricted.jpg",
        id: "image3"
    },
    {
        src:  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/stuff/170407220916-04-iconic-mountains-matterhorn-restricted.jpg",
        id: "image4"
    }
    ];
}


function startPreload() {
    preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
    preload.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);         
    preload.on("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    preload.on("progress", handleFileProgress);
    preload.on("complete", loadComplete);
    preload.on("error", loadError);
    preload.loadManifest(manifest);

}


function handleFileLoad(event) {
    console.log("loading: " + event.item.type);
    if(event.item.id == "image1"){

    }
}


function loadError(evt) {
    console.log("err",evt.text);
}
function handleFileProgress(event) {
    progressText.text = "loading " + (preload.progress*100|0) + " %";
    stage.update();
}
function loadComplete(event) {

}

setupManifest();
startPreload();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like you need to enable CORS on your server/bucket: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: If I upload pictures to a folder with other files, then most likely there will be no errors. The error occurs due to the fact that I refer to a picture on third-party resources. I just need to see how to load in percentage of the picture, I'm testing the site on localhost. Is there a way in google chrome to set the page loading speed, for example, if the pictures were downloaded via the Internet?

Comment: your comment is a separate issue than your original question, so you probably want to ask it as a separate question for better reach, but you can use Chrome devtools with device throttling for that